# font with lowercase e when the font is uppercase

Tags: fonts, typography

[image: Here]'s the text written in the font I'm looking for. I really need that font but could not find it anywhere. I tried online font indentifiers but they all failed. And [image: here]'s the appropriately skewed and contrasted image.

Comment: Shop windows are pretty much hand painted.

Comment: @Scott or vinyl transfers

Comment: It's a pretty standard san-serif font and they used a lower case e in a string of capital letters. Maybe an extremely heavy Helvetica. That should be easy to reproduce without needing a specific font:

Comment: @Scott I don't think any professional stores are hand painted anymore. Unless you go deeper in the city... That's just a very accurate observation that I have to share. All professional business uses vinyl. It's easy to put on, easy to take off, and can be printed with full color. Sure you might see the occasional chain restaurant paint some promotional thing on their window. But that is even more rare now days.

Answer (score 5):

The term you're looking for is "unicase" or "monocase", where uppercase and lowercase are mixed in the same size. The particular font you have there is (or at least is very close to [Meloriac](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/meloriac/?refby=pixilate) by Typodermic Fonts

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: This is a quick attempt with Franklin Gothic heavy. The text is 72 pt. The "e"s are 96 pt]

You can do this with any font almost. Franklin Gothic Heavy seems to come pretty close. I didn't do more than blow up the e's to be the same height as the capital letters.